# Adding objects to dictionary in a loop overwrites previous values

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have three `NSArray`s, and I want to combine them all into a single `NSDictionary`. The problem is that as I iterate through the arrays and create the dictionary, it overwrites the previous object. In the end I only have one object in my dictionary. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<[array0 count]; i++) {
    [dict setObject:[array0 objectAtIndex:i] 
             forKey:@"one"];
    [dict setObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i] f
              orKey:@"two"];
    [dict setObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:i] 
             forKey:@"three"];
}
```

Maybe this will clarify what I mean... 
this is the result I'm going for:

```
{one = array0_obj0, two = array1_obj0, three = array2_obj0},
{one = array0_obj1, two = array1_obj1, three = array2_obj1},
{one = array0_obj2, two = array1_obj2, three = array2_obj2}, 
etc
```

Thanks

Comment: Much as arrays have one object per index, dictionaries have one object per key. You are using the keys `@"one"`, `@"two"`, and `@"three"` in each iteration of the loop, therefore over-writing the one object the dictionary stores per each of those keys. Going back to the array analogy, this is equivalent to always assigning to the same indexes of an array each time through a loop, thus overwriting what was previously at that same index.

Comment: Side note: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"string that has no formatting specifiers"]` doesn't make a lot of sense. Just use the literal string directly.

Comment: See revised answer below

Comment: This piece of code did it for me.

Comment: `code`[allDevices addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                                    [NSArray arrayWithObjects: rowID, name, company, nil]
                            forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"rowID", @"name", @"company", nil]], nil]];`code`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(int i=0; i<[array0 count]; i++) {
    [dict setObject:[array0 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arr0_%d", i]];
    [dict setObject:[array1 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arr1_%d", i]];
    [dict setObject:[array2 objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"arr2_%d", i]];
}
```

Edit - with revised question:

```
self.array0 = @[@"Array0_0",@"Array0_1",@"Array0_2", @"Array0_3"];
self.array1 = @[@"Array1_0",@"Array1_1",@"Array1_2", @"Array1_3"];
self.array2 = @[@"Array2_0",@"Array2_1",@"Array2_2", @"Array2_3"];

NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i< [_array0 count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"one":[_array0 objectAtIndex:i], @"two":[_array1 objectAtIndex:i],@"three":[_array2 objectAtIndex:i]};
    [finalArray addObject:dict];
}

NSLog(@"finalArray = %@", [finalArray description]);
```

Comment: Actually... this doesn't give me what I need. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 5):

## Issue

You are inserting and replacing the same object at the specific key. So all what dictionary has is its last object at the last index.

## Solution

Use this code to add the three arrays into one dictionary with your specific keys.

```
NSDictionary *yourDictinary = @{@"one": array0, @"two": array1, @"three": array3};
```

## Edit

If you need to add objects of your `NSMutableArrays` to one `NSDictionary` you can follow the answer posted by @ElJay, but that's not a good practice, since you are dealing with multiple objects with unique keys.

## Update

To do that thing, we are talking about a single NSMutableArray and multiple NSDictinarys.

Follow this code:

```
NSMutableArray *allObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i=0; i<[array0 count]; i++) {
    dict = @{@"one": array0[i], @"two": array1[i], @"three": array2[i]};
    [allObjects addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: This is not what the user what to do. He want combine all the object in a dictionary and not 3 array in a dictionary. Obviously the user are approaching to hi problem in a bad manner..i don't know what he want to do.

Comment: @MatteoGobbi check out the OP, he wants to add 3 arrays into one dictionary! He is not telling that he wants to add all the objects in the same NSDictionary. That makes no sense with specific keys.

Comment: His efforts suggest that @MatteoGobbi is right.  He seems to be wanting all the objects (however weird that sounds) into a single dictionary.

Comment: @ElJay I was following his question, but if I missunderstood him, I also edited the question, but that's not a good way to do things (I don't know what you plan by adding all objects into one NSDictionary)

Comment: Totally agree with ya on that.

Comment: @d.barrett000 you are actually wrote about adding multiple NSDictionarys in one NSMutableArray. I'll update the answer

Comment: FYI, the reason I need to do this is because I have to create a JSON object from the dictionary.

Comment: @d.barrett000 you can also create JSON Array

Answer (score 3):

You're reusing the keys `("one", "two" and "three")` through each iteration of the loop. Keys in an `NSDictionary` have to be unique.

Answer (score -1):

If you want many dictionary but only three keys, you should save each dict in an array.

Comment: This question is OK but provide more information, because that's why you are getting downvotes!